# Pagination not working AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I want to make a pagination of the results of the AJAX request. Pagination does not work. After clicking the page number, only the address and everything (example: / page / 3 /) change. Where did I make a mistake?

**PAGE.PHP**

```
<div class="site-content clearfix">
       <h1>Alex Blog</h1>
        <?php
          $ourCurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');
          $aboutPosts = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'tour',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => 3,
          ));

          if ($aboutPosts->have_posts()) :
            while ($aboutPosts->have_posts()) :
              $aboutPosts->the_post();
              ?> 
        <span> <?php the_title(); ?> </span>
                  <br>

  <?php endwhile;
            echo paginate_links(array(
              'total' => $aboutPosts->max_num_pages
            ));

          endif;
   ?>   
</div>
```

**FUNCTION.PHP**

```
function tourcat_ajax_by_order() { if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
    $posts_per_page = et_get_option( 'divi_archivenum_posts' ) ;
        $args = array(              // WP query args
              'post_type' => 'tour',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page
          );
     $tour_query = new WP_Query($args);
       if ( $tour_query->have_posts() ) {  // Have posts start here
        while ( $tour_query->have_posts() ) {   // While starts here
            $tour_query->the_post();
          ?>
                  <span> <?php the_title(); ?> </span>
                  <br>
          <?php}   
echo paginate_links(array(
              'total' => $aboutPosts->max_num_pages
            ));}  
            else {
            echo 'No results found';}
     wp_reset_postdata();}
           die();}
```

**JS CODE**

```
function tourcat_orderby_posts() {
         $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action':'tourcat_ajax_by_order',  
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request 
                    $(".tour_parent_div").html(data);  
                },
                error: function(errorThrown) {}
            });}
```

Comment: No idea. Did you check if you actually get the right values in? Could it for instance be that the page number never reaches your PHP code? Or that it does, but not as `paged`. And if that works.. Where do you actually *use* `$ourCurrentPage`?

Comment: Show the JS code too.

Comment: https://lab.mark5designs.com/alex/  My site. See please.

Comment: you didnt use page ajax on pagination.

Comment: I using pagination for AJAX request.

Comment: when i click on pagination number it is redirecting.you are not calling ajax request.

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not not implemented correctly, you can try the following:

### PAGE.PHP

#### Use the same markup and call after adding a wrapper to the content:

```
<div class="site-content clearfix">
       <h1>Alex Blog</h1>
       <div id="page-posts-wrapper">
        <?php
          $ourCurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');
          $aboutPosts = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'tour',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => 3,
          ));

          if ($aboutPosts->have_posts()) :
            while ($aboutPosts->have_posts()) :
              $aboutPosts->the_post();
              ?> 
        <span> <?php the_title(); ?> </span>
                  <br>

  <?php endwhile;
            echo paginate_links(array(
              'total' => $aboutPosts->max_num_pages
            ));

          endif;
   ?>   
       </div>
</div>
```

### FUNCTION.PHP

#### Load js file and localize query data to use later for page generation:

```
function custom_assets_39828328() {
        // Correct the path and js file name before using.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-pagination',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-pagination.js', array(), '1.0', true );

        global $wp_query;
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'query_vars' => json_encode( $wp_query->query )
        ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_assets_39828328' );
```

#### Write the callback function that will be used when browsing the pages:

```
/**
 * AJAX Pagination function
 */
function my_ajax_pagination_72372732() {

    $query_vars = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query_vars'] ), true );


    $query_vars['post_type'] = 'tour';
    $query_vars['paged'] = $_POST['page'];
    $query_vars['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 3;


    $posts = new WP_Query( $query_vars );
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $posts;


    if( ! $posts->have_posts() ) { 
        echo 'No results found';
    }
    else {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) { 
            $posts->the_post();
            ?>
                <span> <?php the_title(); ?> </span><br>      
            <?php

        }
            echo paginate_links(array('total' => $posts->max_num_pages  ));
    }

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination_72372732' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination_72372732' );
```

### JS Code

#### Pass the necessary details through Ajax to the call function and display response:

```
(function($) {
    function find_page_number(element) {
        element.find('span').remove();
        return parseInt(element.html());
    }
    $(document).on('click', 'a.page-numbers', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        page = find_page_number($(this).clone());
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_pagination',
                query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
                page: page
            },
            success: function(html) {
                $('#page-posts-wrapper').empty();
                $('#page-posts-wrapper').append(html);
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

You can also replace the ajax callback query args with this (optional):

```
$new_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'paged' => $_POST['page'],
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
 );
```

Will work in both cases.

Comment: I noticed that the buttons next and previous do not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to have the results using ajax without reloading the page, the following code might help : Hope this will work

paginate,js  :

```
$('.pagi').on('click',function()
{   
    var pageid=$(this).data('page');
    var page_total=$(this).data('total');
    var data={
            action: "ajax_by_order",
            pageid: pageid,
            page_total:page_total
        };

    $.post(sitesettings.ajaxurl, data,function(res){
        var cont = JSON.parse(res);
        $('.result-content').html(cont.html);
        $('.pagin').html(cont.pagination_html);

    });
});
```

Function.php

```
function paginate_script() {
        // Correct the path and js file name before using.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'paginate',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/paginate.js', array(), '1.0', true );

        wp_localize_script( 'paginate', 'sitesettings', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'paginate_script' );

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_by_order', 'tristup_ajax_by_order' ); //witout logged in
add_action("wp_ajax_ajax_by_order","tristup_ajax_by_order");           //logged in

function tristup_ajax_by_order()
{
    $page_id=$_POST['page_id'];
    $page_total=$_POST['page_total'];

    $args['post_type']='tour';
    $args['post_status']='publish';
    $args['posts_per_page']=3;

    if($page_id>0)
    {
        $args['offset']=(3*$page_id);       
    }
    $aboutPosts = new WP_Query($args);

    $output='';
    $pagination_html='';
    if ( $aboutPosts->have_posts() ) 
    {
        while ( $aboutPosts->have_posts() ) : $aboutPosts->the_post();

            $output.='<div>'.get_the_title().'</div>';

        endwhile; 
    }

    for($i=0;$i<$page_total;$i++)
    {
        $j=$i+1;
        $pagination_html.='<span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pagi" data-page="'.$i.'" data-total="'.$page_total.'">'.$j.'</span>';
    }

    $result['html']=$flag;
    $result['pagination_html']=$pagination_html;

    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}//end of function
```

Page.php

```
<div class="site-content clearfix">
       <h1>Alex Blog</h1>
        <?php
                $args['post_type']='tour';
                $args['post_status']='publish';
                $args['posts_per_page']=3;
                $aboutPosts = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <div class="result-content">
        <?php 
                if ($aboutPosts->have_posts()) :
                    while ($aboutPosts->have_posts()) : $aboutPosts->the_post();
        ?> 
                <div> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>               

        <?php 
                    endwhile; 
                endif;          
        ?>   
        </div>
        <div class="pagin">
        <?php 
            for($i=0;$i<$aboutPosts->max_num_pages;$i++)
            {
                $j=$i+1;
        ?>
                <span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pagi" data-page="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-total="<?php echo $aboutPosts->max_num_pages; ?>"><?php echo $j; ?></span>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
</div>
```